# Wahoo wont show waypoint

Tags: navigation

My wahoo element roam doenst show waypoints when loaded

I have tried dozen maps.. and still no go

My friend's element bolt has the same problem

Im using android and he is on ios.

Comment: What kind of waypoints? How did you set up them? How do you try to view them?

Comment: It is downloaded from 'randonneur korea' website. 
I know it is legit file.. because most other people here use garmin and they don't have problems.. 

In fact, my wahoo worked fine until few months ago.  
Some maps I loaded up in the past, which I know they worked fine in the past, now doesn't work anymore.. (no waypoint)

One example would be http://www.korearandonneurs.kr:8080/jsp/permanent/info-PT02.htm (you can click on gpx file and download)

Comment: I am lost. So does not not show any waypoints at all? Or only some particular waypoints from some particular file?

Comment: no waypoints at all.. only destination..

Comment: Is it a duff firmware ''upgrade''?

Comment: So to clarify, you have downloaded unofficial maps from a third-party website.  Try disabling all of that and see if proper function returns.

Comment: I just confirmed, many other people here have same problem .. 
they say, same map works if you upload it from pc via usb. but won't work if you upload it through mobile ..

Comment: Some map files don’t have waypoints depending on how the file was created or how it was exported. IIRC for Garmin the waypoints are in a different folder to the actual map. When I get some time I’ll try uploading your gpx, I suspect it’s missing the waypoints so all you’ll get is a start and finish

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to download/use the .TCX version instead? I also have a Wahoo Elemnt Bolt and do randonneur rides and the controls (waypoints) are not displayed which has been a problem. I just read on this website: https://burlycross.wordpress.com/2019/07/23/wahoo-help-guide/
that maybe Wahoo like .TCX file type better. I will try soon and post again if successful. Please let me know if you find a solution also. Hope to see you at PBP in August 2023!

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Please make sure you update your answer when you try this to tell us if it works.